# recursively filter json data for search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter, uisearchbar

I'm trying to code a search bar filter for a react table.

The difficult part is the JSON data structure which could have parent-child relationship of unknown depth, E.g.:

```
  data = [
    {
      input: "row 0 ",
      output: "output of the first row"
      subRows: [],
    },
    {
      input: "row 1",
      output: "output of the second row"
      subRows: [
        {
          input: "third row 1.0",
          output: "output of the 3° row"
          subRows: [
            {
              input: "row 1.0.0",
              output: "output of the third row"
              subRows: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          input: "row 1.1",
          output: "output of 2 rows after the third (fifth)"
          subRows: []
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Additional info: every object of the above JSON is represented in my html(jsx) table as a row and his subRows are others rows which can be expanded by a user click.

I thought I could handle it with ES6 filter function but I can't figure out how.

This is what I expect as result if a user write for instance in the search bar: "third"

```
        {
          input: "third row 1.0",
          output: "output of the 3° row"
          subRows: []
        },
        {
          input: "row 1.1",
          output: "output of 2 rows after the third (fifth)",
          subRows: []
        },
```

Here's the code I have:

```
 const updateFilter = (filterValue) => {
   let results = data.filter(function f(row) {
      if (Object.values(row).includes(filterValue.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }
      if (row.subRows && row.subRows.length > 0) {
        return (row.subRows = row.subRows.filter(f));
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
  };
 }
```

here the code in codePen: https://codepen.io/ardiz90/pen/yLajjRQ?editors=0012

Thank you for the help!

EDIT: Turns out I can't flatten the rows because the table needs to have the data in the tree structure to be able to render it, so the solution written below to flatten the rows is not feasible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the nested objects first, and then filter the Values accordingly. I also think that your filtering mechanism with `Object.values(...).includes(...)` would not work correctly.

Here is a Example for flatten the Objects and filtering them:

```js
// returns a Array containing the element itself and its children recursively
function flattenWithSubRows(entries) {
    return entries.flatMap(entry => [
        entry, ...flattenWithSubRows(entry.subRows)
    ]);
}

// gets an array containing only the objects 
// containing the searchString in a string property
function getAllMatchingItems(searchString, array) {
    const isMatching = entry => Object.values(entry)
        .filter(val => typeof val === 'string')
        .map(val => val.toLowerCase())
        .some(val => val.includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));

    return flattenWithSubRows(array).filter(isMatching)
}

const filtered = getAllMatchingItems("third", data);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: can we also empty the subRows property inside flattenWithSubRows? otherwise we will have duplicate filtered values right?

Comment: yes you can absolutely do that, if you do not need the actual subRows in the filtered Array