# How to recursively filter tree JSON in React/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, filter, tree

I need to filter this JSON tree data for a search (filter tree) functionality.
The structure looks like this:

The Array filter > map is only going to the first level.
How do I traverse up to the last level of child (filter should work on all levels after Customers) and filter accordingly using a string (includes logic)

```
{
   "path":"Customers",
   "sha":"Customers",
   "lazy":false,
   "type":"tree",
   "tree":[
      {
         "path":"Bob Rivers",
         "type":"tree",
         "sha":"Bob Rivers",
         "lazy":false,
         "tree":[
            {
               "path":"Services",
               "type":"tree",
               "sha":"Services",
               "lazy":true,
               "url":"http://localhost:3000/services",
               "tree":[
                  {
                     "path":"Service_X",
                     "type":"tree",
                     "sha":"Service_X",
                     "lazy":true,
                     "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_X",
                     "tree":[
                        {
                           "lazy":true,
                           "path":"Service_X_child",
                           "mode":"040000",
                           "type":"tree",
                           "sha":"Service_X_child",
                           "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_X_child",
                           "tree":[
                              {
                                 "lazy":true,
                                 "path":"ABC",
                                 "mode":"040000",
                                 "type":"blob",
                                 "sha":"ABC",
                                 "url":""
                              },
                              {
                                 "lazy":true,
                                 "path":"DEF",
                                 "mode":"040000",
                                 "type":"blob",
                                 "sha":"DEF",
                                 "url":""
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "lazy":true,
                           "path":"Service_X_child_2",
                           "mode":"040000",
                           "type":"tree",
                           "sha":"Service_X_child_2",
                           "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_X_child_2"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "path":"Service_Y",
                     "type":"tree",
                     "sha":"Service_Y",
                     "lazy":true,
                     "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_Y"
                  }
               ],
            }
         ],
      }
   ],
}
```

Sample Input is if the search filter = "DEF" (path will be checked), the data will be reduced to this one

```
{
   "path":"Customers",
   "sha":"Customers",
   "lazy":false,
   "type":"tree",
   "tree":[
      {
         "path":"Bob Rivers",
         "type":"tree",
         "sha":"Bob Rivers",
         "lazy":false,
         "tree":[
            {
               "path":"Services",
               "type":"tree",
               "sha":"Services",
               "lazy":true,
               "url":"http://localhost:3000/services",
               "tree":[
                  {
                     "path":"Service_X",
                     "type":"tree",
                     "sha":"Service_X",
                     "lazy":true,
                     "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_X",
                     "tree":[
                        {
                           "lazy":true,
                           "path":"Service_X_child",
                           "mode":"040000",
                           "type":"tree",
                           "sha":"Service_X_child",
                           "url":"http://localhost:3000/Service_X_child",
                           "tree":[
                              {
                                 "lazy":true,
                                 "path":"DEF",
                                 "mode":"040000",
                                 "type":"blob",
                                 "sha":"DEF",
                                 "url":""
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
            }
         ],
      }
   ],
}
```

I have tried the following solution/s but did not work:
[recursively filter json data for search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613247/recursively-filter-json-data-for-search-bar)

> This one explicitly mentioned that flatting the JSON tree data to array did not solve his issue

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes/

Comment: You know that react is a UI library and not a JSON parsing tool?

Comment: Of course, I am asking how to solve this problem using React libraries and Javascript syntax. I just did not include JS code since what I have was not working

Comment: But that's why you need to include it. The example in the question should be your previous attempt. A [mcve]

Comment: What if your searched node has children, should those children be included -- without further filtering? Secondly, what does "string (includes logic)" mean? Do you have a specific syntax  used by that string? Which? What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const TreeNode = ({node , searchString}) => {
    if(!node.tree){
      return node.path.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())? node:null
    }

    node.tree = node.tree.map(childNode => TreeNode(
      {
        node:childNode, searchString        
      }
    )).filter(n => n);
    return node.tree.length? node:null;
  }
```

This recursive function solved my problem